# Laravel 8 - Disable migrations for specific package

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

Scenario is the following:
I'm building a software where the frontend and the programm that does the work are separated from each other. To have the frontend be able to use the models of the worker-programm, I've build a package that holds them. The package has the following code to it's provider:

```
public function boot()
    {
        if($this->app->runningInConsole()){
            $this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__ . '/MyPackageMigrations');
        }
    }
```

Now my problem is that I want those migrations to be run when the `artisan migrate` command is run in the worker-programm, but not in the UI-programm, since both databases are separated from each other aswell. Is there a way to supress those migrations in the UI-programm?

Greetings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using `loadMigrationsFrom()` in the `boot()` method of your `ServiceProvider`, you can use `$this->puiblishes()` which gives you control over publishing migrations rather than having them load automatically.

```
public function boot()
{
    if ($this->app->runningInConsole()) {
        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__ . '/../database/migrations/create_models_table.php.stub' 
                => database_path('migrations/' . date('Y_m_d_His', time()) . 'create_models_table.php'),
            // you can add any number of migrations here
        ], 'migrations');
    }
}
```

Then all you need to do is publish the migrations in the projects you want to use the migrations in:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Husky110\Husky110Package\Husky110PackageServiceProvider" --tag="migrations"
```

**Update**

You can check for the existence of migration by doing something like:

```
if (!class_exists('CreateModelsTable')) {
    // perform migration
}
```

If you have migrations which alter the structure of a table, you might do:

```
if (!class_exists('AlterModelsTableAddField')) {
    // perform migration
}
```

Comment: Great idea, but I wonder what happens when I add a new migration, cause the package is in kinda state of flux (aka development) at the moment... Would it help to set the timestamp to a static value, so the migrations do not get published twice? I'm thinking about adding the pubish- and migrate-commands to the composer.json at the worker...

Comment: @Husky110 I have updated my answer to give you a possible solution.